# Canvas sometimes does not resize to width and height

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I tried to resize my canvas in Javascript below:

```
'use strict';

(_ => {
  // 'board' is the canvas
  const board = document.querySelector('.board');
  const ctx = board.getContext('2d');

  initialise();

  function initialise() {
    board.width = board.clientWidth;
    board.height = board.clientHeight;
  }
})();
```

However, the canvas sometimes resizes itself, and sometimes don't (defaults back to `0 * 0` with CSS width and height set to `100%`). I've tried searching it online and there was nothing like this issue. Is there anything wrong that I've done here?

I am using `Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)` if that helps. Thanks in advance!

#### Edit 1

I added the following line of code to the HTML `<head>`:

```
  ...
  <script src="app.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

The `defer` attribute should cause the script to only load after the page has finished parsing.

#### Edit 2

The following is my CSS:

```
.board {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Hence `board.clientWidth` and `board.clientHeight` should get the correct sizes, but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure the canvas has loaded completely? Maybe a layout issue, not sure if `client*` is guaranteed to give the correct results, i.e. forces all layout necessary.

Comment: @H.B. How do I ensure the canvas has loaded completely?

Comment: May be you should try `board.style.width` and `board.style.height`?

Comment: I'd expect an error if it has not. If the script is executed before the canvas is loaded you should get null from the `querySelector`. If the script is placed after the element in the document, it should be loaded.

Comment: @MohammadUsman: That probably will return empty string, unless that style property was set. It does not calculate sizes.

Comment: @H.B. ahan. I see now. I thought `board` is a wrapper around canvas.

Comment: `defer` tell the script to execute when finished parsing,. But I'm not sure how that compares to the DOMReady,.. So I would still place this inside a DOMready callback.

Comment: interesting question. with `defer`, is the css applied before or after the script executes.

Answer (score 0):

If the script is in the head, you probably want to wait for the document to be ready first:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
        // Your code.
    }
}
```

Comment: @qwerty: It's not quite the same (though i missed that attribute), could you check if it changes anything. `defer` scripts trigger before `DOMContentLoaded`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `requestAnimationFrame` for setting the width and height for the canvas.
This solution worked in all my projects and I use the full screen canvas a lot

```js
const requestAnimation = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimation;

function getId(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

const canvas = getId('canvas');

function SetUp() {
  canvas.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  Update();
}
 
function Update() {
  // allmoost fullscreen canvas
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.95;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.95;
  
  // creates a black rectangle
  canvas.ctx.fillRect(canvas.width / 4, canvas.height / 4,canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)
  
  requestAnimationFrame(Update);
}

SetUp();
```

```css
canvas {    
  position: fixed;
  border: solid red;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

## parsed != DOMContentLoaded

Yes, that's the moral of this story that had me scratching my head for days.

`defer` does not gurantee that the DOM is primed and ready. So, the corrected code should be:

```
const board = document.querySelector('.board');
const ctx = board.getContext('2d');

initialise();

function initialise() {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    board.width = board.clientWidth;
    board.height = board.clientHeight;
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're setting the width and height on load, becouse that code runs after load on DOMContentLoaded events, right?. If not set it and also recall the initialize() method on window resize.

Something like

```
document.addEventListener("resize", initialize);
```

Comment: Althought you're using the defer tag on the script, have you tried waiting for the document to load and then executing the code?